# solve without zorn's lemma --> set of all nilpotent elements in some prime ideal in commutative ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

can you tell me how to solve without using zorns lemma
My approach:-
consider a is nilpotent.  Then $a^n = 0$ for some $a\in R$. $a. a^{n-1} = 0 \in P, where \hspace {1mm} P \hspace {1mm}is\hspace {1mm}prime\hspace {1mm} some \hspace {1mm} ideal; \Rightarrow either \hspace {1mm} a = 0 or \hspace {1mm} a^{n-1} = 0 \hspace {1mm}which \hspace {1mm} recursively \hspace {1mm} $ leads to $a=0$. Can you tell me is this correct?

Comment: What is the actual statement that you want to prove?

Comment: STATEMENT I WANT TO PROVE:- Let N be set of all nilpotent elements of commutative ring R. show that N $\subseteq$P for each prime ideal P of R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused about the definition of a prime ideal. In particular, your claim that $a^{n} = 0 \in P$ implies that $a = 0$ or $a^{n-1} = 0$. This is demonstrably untrue. I'm also a bit confused as to why one might appeal to Zorn's lemma.

**Claim:** Let $N$ denote the set of nilpotent elements of a commutative ring $R$. Given any prime ideal $P$ of $R$, $N \subset P$.

*Proof:*

Let $P$ be prime and $a \in N$. Then there exists an integer $n$ such that $a^{n} = 0 \in P$. Since $P$ is prime, we obtain $a \in P$ or $a^{n-1} \in P$. If $a \not \in P$, then we see that $a^{n-1} \in P$ and using the same logic, that $a^{n-i} \in P$ for each $i < n$. This is, of course, a contradiction since it would imply $a \in P$.